# How to get month number or name in cds view

Tags: abap, hana-studio, cds

I am creating a CDS view in Hana studio where i want to get month number or name from date (YYYYMMDD) in report, but I am unable to find any function like month or anything else,

Please help.

Comment: Very Nice,,its working fine,,Thanks

Comment: Hi Arun, glad to know that it works, would you please mark the answer as the correct one? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join table t247 that has the required information:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZDD_DATE_T'
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
define view zdd_date_test
  with parameters p_date:abap.dats(8)
  as select from demo_expressions left outer join t247 as date_information on date_information.spras = $session.system_language {
  key mandt, 
  key id, 
  num1, 
  num2, 
  date_information.ltx as long_text
  } where date_information.mnr = substring(:p_date, 5, 2);
```

This will return the following data from table demo_expressions:

```
id,num1,num2,long_text
0,90,18,November
1,19,99,November
2,83,82,November
3,87,92,November
4,15,56,November
5,29,4,November
6,38,87,November
7,74,13,November
8,26,99,November
9,35,50,November
```

The use of `substring(:p_date, 5, 2)` is what you use to extract the month number and then join table `t247`.